# Show First instance of records with duplicate values in tow colums

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have these values in a table called advertisements:

```
id         sitecatid      locationid
1             12            3
2             12            6
3             12            8
4             12            8 
5             12            8 
6             10            18 
7             13            20
8             14            21
```

I want to return the results like this:

```
sitecatid      locationid
    12            3
    10            6
    13            8
    14            18
                  20
                  21
```

Basically I only want the first instance of any record with a unique sitecatid
 and locationid.
I tried this query But the result not correct:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT sitecatid, locationid 
    FROM advertisements 
    WHERE MATCH (sitetitle,sitedescription) 
AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status='approved'
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this doesn't really look like a relational database problem to me.  This is something which I'd rather handle in an app language like C# or Java.

Comment: my source code is PHP and database is mysql And my question tag is php,mysql what problem in my ask?

Comment: What you're asking for isn't what databases usually do with their data, because it is not relational.  You might need dynamic SQL for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select b.sitecatid,d.locationid from 
(SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row_number,
       a.sitecatid
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT sitecatid
        FROM   tbl_test) a
       , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r) as b
right join
(SELECT @rownum_2 := @rownum_2 + 1 AS row_number,
       c.locationid
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT locationid
        FROM   tbl_test) c
       , (SELECT @rownum_2 := 0) s) as d
on b.row_number = d.row_number
```